# Hyperlink to a website using node-webkit

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, node-webkit

Please guys, I need someone to help me out with a full coded tutorial on how to open a website from a node webkit desktop application on windows OS.

Yes! I have searched and I saw gui.Shell.openExternal("http://www.example.org") but I do not know how to link it up especially using the html hyperlink(a) tag!

Thanks!

Comment: does this help: `<a href='...' onclick='gui.Shell.openExternal(this.href);return false'>...`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found a way to do it here is the code I used.

var gui = require('nw.gui');

In your a tag for linking in html, create an id = "GoToWebsite"

document.getElementById('GoToWebsite').onclick = function(){gui.Shell.openExternal('http://www.nickzom.org');};